# Stacking arrays column-wise in Julia

Tags: arrays, stack, julia

I am trying to stack two 1D arrays in a column on top of each other.

```
a = [] #1D array
b = [] #1D array
c = reshape(a, b, 1)           # I am expecting it to put array 'b' under array 'a'
```

May I know is this the correct syntax and method to stack arrays in Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> a = [1, 2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> b = [3, 4]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 3
 4

julia> vcat(a, b)
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4

julia> [a; b] # the same as vcat but with a shorter syntax
4-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
```

See also https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-array-concatenation.